# Can ideal gas equation be used in presence of gravity?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

While assuming the ideal gas we need  to neglect gravity and other forces acting on the molecules but I have seen in many questions that ideal gas equation is used even in presence of gravity
Please tell the actual way in which we can use ideal gas equation in such situations
Consider the following question in which
**A tall cylindrical vessel with gaseous nitrogen is located in a uniform gravitational field in which the free fall acceleration is equal to g if temperature of the nitrogen varies  along the height  so that its density is the same throughout the volume find the temperature gradient dT/dh**

Comment: An ideal gas is still affected by gravity, and that does not impact whether it is ideal or not. Air is darn close to ideal, but the reason you have 1 atmosphere of pressure on you at sea level is all about gravity.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the ideal gas equation in the presence of gravity, but you need to use it smartly. The ideal gas equation reads
$$ PV = nRT $$
We are told that we have constant density $\rho = \frac{m}{V}$   of the gas throughout the tube (Which is a very rough approximation, to say the least). It will be convenient to calculate this in terms of the molar density $\rho_n = \frac{n}{V}$. Since the mole number and the mass are proportional to one another, we can also say that this density will be constant throughout the tube.

The pressure at a depth h (meaning we have a column of height h separating us from the top of the fluid) for a fluid of constant density is simply $$P = \rho g h = m_N \rho_n g h = m_N \frac{n}{V} g h $$ with $m_N$ the molar mass of nitrogen.

Going back to the ideal gas equation
$$ PV = m_N \frac{n}{V} g h V =  m_N n g h = nRT \implies T = \frac{m_N g h}{R}.$$
The gradient is then $$ \frac{dT}{dh} = \frac{m_N g }{R}.$$